# Killing code when the password is entered

Tags: excel, vba

I want to block all cells in a worksheet, except with an admin password.
I want to stop the script when the user writes his password, he can have access to the worksheet until closing the worksheet.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim Pass As String 
Pass = "Test"

If Intersect(Target, Range("b6:b82, f6:f82, j6:j82, n6:n82, r6:r82")) Is Nothing Then 
    MsgBox "Vous devez disposer d'un accès administrateur pour modifier cette cellule." 
    frmLogin.Show 
    passform = frmLogin.txtPassword.Value 
    If passform <> Pass Then 
        MsgBox "Mot de passe érroné", vbExclamation, "Error" 
        Range("b6").Select 
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

I tried `Application.Wait` and `End`.

Comment: Probably with a simple `While passform <> Pass Then ... Loop`, if it's meant to be for the total workbook, you can put it in Workbook_Open(), otherwise you'll have to declare a Public variable above all your subs and then encapsulate your first If with another `If passform <> pass Then`. Public variables should retain their value until the workbook is closed. Lastly, you could also just protect the worksheet and have the other cells unprotected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correct, you don't want to "kill the script"

- you don't want to run it when you select another cell within the procedure because the user put in a wrong password
- you don't want to run it, if the user has authenticated as admin

Regarding the first point: set Application.EnableEvents to false

Regarding the second point: Use a flag, e.g. `m_isAdmin` on module-level

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Const Pass As String = "Test"
Private m_isAdmin As Boolean

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If m_isAdmin = True Then Exit Sub 'no check necessary

Dim passform As String

If Intersect(Target, Range("b6:b82, f6:f82, j6:j82, n6:n82, r6:r82")) Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Vous devez disposer d'un accès administrateur pour modifier cette cellule."
    frmLogin.Show
    passform = frmLogin.txtPassword.Value
    If passform <> Pass Then
        MsgBox "Mot de passe érroné", vbExclamation, "Error"
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("A1").Select
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    Else
        'if password is ok, set the module-level varialbe to true
        m_isAdmin = True
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help ! It's exactly what i needed ! I just removed the variable passform because it was useless and i had an error but now it's work fine. Unfortunatly i learned that vba doesn't work on excel online so i did it for nothing.. I'm actually sad..